# Why is UITest.Maps filename null during UITestClass.Saving?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm writing a coded ui package extension, and have it hooked up like this:

```
public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
      {
         if (!_initialized)
         {
            _initialized = true;
            UITestClass.Saving += OnUiTestSave;
         }

         return null;
      }
```

Then inside that method:

```
private void OnUiTestSave(object sender, UITestEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e.UITest != null && e.UITest.Maps != null && e.UITest.Maps.Count == 1)
         {
            foreach (TopLevelElement topLevelElement in e.UITest.Maps[0].TopLevelWindows)
            {
               LoopThroughAll(topLevelElement, topLevelElement.Id);
            }
         }
      }
```

Notice in the above code **e.UITest.Maps[0]** actually exists and is totally valid, but I need to get the filename. The property exists but it's always null.

Is this a Microsoft bug?

Comment: What else is stored in the Maps array apart form the first element which is null?